# Is there a way to configure IntelliJ+Scala code style to align the if/then statement to the else statement?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, code-formatting

There are times when an `if`/`then`/`else` is too big to fit on one line, or the single-line syntax hides the relationships between the statements:

```scala
if ( someCondition ) thenStatement() else elseStatement()
```

But in context, the traditional multi-line format is overkill, or actually hurts readability:

```scala
if ( someCondition )
  thenStatement()
else
  elseStatement()
```

So it makes sense to split it at the `else` keyword:

```scala
if ( someCondition ) thenStatement()
else elseStatement()
```

In those situations, especially where the two statements are somehow related, and it would help to see them one under the other to see how they differ, I like to align them, like so:

```scala
if ( someCondition ) thenStatement()
else                 elseStatement()
```

Unfortunately, if I ever tell IntelliJ to reformat my code, that alignment is lost.  Is there a configuration which would allow the `if`/`then` statement part to be aligned vertically with the `else` statement part, as in the above?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such code style settings yet.
I've created a tracking YouTrack ticket for that one, please vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-16234